# .htaccess redirect 301 is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a bit of a problem with my redirects. I have around 2000 redirects like this in my .htaccess:

```
# index.php?cPath=24_60 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24_60
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки? [R=301,L]
```

and it's all working fine except these:

```
# index.php?cPath=24_60_105
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24_60_105
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки/Дървени-подматрачни-рамки? [R=301,L]

# index.php?cPath=24_60_106 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24_60_106 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки/Метални-подматрачни-рамки? [R=301,L]

# index.php?cPath=24_60_107 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24_60_107 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки/Подматрачни-рамки-с-повдигащ-механизъм? [R=301,L]

#index.php?cPath=24_60_108 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24_60_108 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки/Подматрачни-рамки/Подматрачни-рамки-с-крака? [R=301,L]
```

They all redirect to /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки and I can't seem to put my finger on exactly what is the problem.
My other rules might matter so here they are:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

all 2000+ 301 Redirects
...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing anchor `$` in your regex. Fix it by using:

```
# index.php?cPath=24_60 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24_60(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /Матраци/Подматрачни-рамки? [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise `^cPath=24_60` will also match

```
cPath=24_60_105
cPath=24_60_106
cPath=24_60_107
```

etc.